# React native drop shadow

Tags: react-native, dropshadow

I need to drop shadow option to add to buttons in the Android app.
In react, native default options (shadowColor, shadowOpacity, shadowRadius) only work with ios versions. Android only work with elevation option.
Does anyone know how to do this? I used react-native-shadow but it older on not supported to latest react native versions it got errors from SVG component even we installed it manually.

Comment: to add shadow you can use elevation only, with elevation you can use shadowOpacity shadowOffset and shadowRadius accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can use the React Native `Platform` module to set an OS-specific style. For example:

```js
import { Platform, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

// your component //////

const styles = StyleSheet.create({        
  button: {

    // cross-platform css

    ...Platform.select({
      ios: {
        shadowColor: rgba(0,0,0),
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 5
      },
      android: {
        elevation: 5
      },
    }),
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below library:

https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview

It will fulfill your requirements

Answer (score 0):

In react-native, you should avoid writing platform specific code.

When required to handle tasks like this - you should use an existing library or create your own.

[react-native-drop-shadow](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-drop-shadow) is a good example of one of these cases. Or you could use a similar method to the one I have used in my app and just include the elevation and shadow styles in a single style object.

**No External Library Required:**

```json
elevation: 5,              // Android
shadowColor: '#030002',    // Android, iOS & Web
shadowOpacity: 0.25,       // iOS & Web
shadowRadius: 5            // iOS & web
```